# Bubble Sort With Array and Termination

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

I want to write code where a user enters 5 input and sorts it ascendingly and if a user inputs -1 it terminates.

I've done the bubble sort but I couldn't implement the if structure.

1. Is there a problem with my syntax?
2. İf it isn't, then which structure can I use to make it work?
3. When I run it, it gives expected primary expression before "else" mistake.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <conio.h>

 main()
  {
     int n[10];
     int i,j,temp;

     for(i=0;i<5;i++)/*Wating to user */
         {
           printf("%d. Sayi giriniz(Enter NUmber)",i+1);
           scanf("%d",&n[i]);
                             }
             if(n[i] != -1) 
               for(i=0;i<4;i++)   
                    for(j=i+1;j<5;j++)
                       if(n[i]>n[j])
                        {
                        temp=n[i];
                        n[i]=n[j];
                        n[j]=temp;
                        }                                                    

                     printf("\n");  
                     for(i=0;i<5;i++)
                      printf("%d. sayı(number):%d\n",i+1,n[i]);

            else
               {
                  break; 
              }                     
           getch();
           return 0;

     }
```

Comment: You're missing a lot of braces.

Comment: I am really new which ones?

Comment: I tried for 2 hours couldn't make it work

Comment: Can't get what you want. Do u want to take exactly five inputs, or may be less than 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your initial for loop ends with i = 5. After it you test n[i], so n[5] which was not initialized. You should test n[i] inside the loop and break if it's -1.

Defining the variables in the loop would avoid these errors:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) { 
  ...
}
```

Extra hint: Try to indent your code properly:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
main()
{
  int n[10];
  int i,j,temp;

  for(i=0;i<5;i++)/*Wating to user */
  {
    printf("%d. Sayi giriniz(Enter NUmber)",i+1);
    scanf("%d",&n[i]);
  }
  if(n[i] != -1) 
    for(i=0;i<4;i++)   
      for(j=i+1;j<5;j++)
        if(n[i]>n[j])
        {
          temp=n[i];
          n[i]=n[j];
          n[j]=temp;
        }                                                    

  printf("\n");  
  for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    printf("%d. say?(number):%d\n",i+1,n[i]);

  // I don't understand how this compiles, this else is not attached
  // to any if.
  else  
  {
    break; 
  }                     
  getch();
  return 0;
}
```

You can fix like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#define NUMBER_OF_NUMBERS 5
int main()
{
  int n[NUMBER_OF_NUMBERS];

  for(int i=0;i<NUMBER_OF_NUMBERS;i++)  // User enters 5 digits.
  {
    printf("%d. Sayi giriniz(Enter NUmber)",i+1);
    scanf("%d",&n[i]);
    if(n[i] == -1)
      return 1;
  }

  // Sort
  for(int i=0;i<NUMBER_OF_NUMBERS - 1;i++)   
    for(int j=i+1;j<NUMBER_OF_NUMBERS;j++)
      if(n[i]>n[j])
      {
        int temp=n[i];
        n[i]=n[j];
        n[j]=temp;
      }                                                    

  printf("\n");  
  for(int i=0;i<NUMBER_OF_NUMBERS;i++)
    printf("%d. say?(number):%d\n",i+1,n[i]);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where should i place else?

Comment: You don't need it if you return when n[i] == -1: return exits the main function so there's no need of a else. If you absolutely want an else, you can use a boolean to memorize if the user typed -1 or not, and then sort and print the result or not.

Comment: Edited the code to place the local variables definitions locally.

Answer (score 1):

I've indented your program as the compiler sees it, with comments:

```
int main()
{
    int n[10];
    int i,j,temp;

    for(i=0;i<5;i++)/*Wating to user */
    {
        printf("%d. Sayi giriniz(Enter NUmber)",i+1);
        scanf("%d",&n[i]);
    }
    if(n[i] != -1) 
        for(i=0;i<4;i++)   
            for(j=i+1;j<5;j++)
                if(n[i]>n[j])
                {
                    temp=n[i];
                    n[i]=n[j];
                    n[j]=temp;
                }
            /* Loop ends */
        /* Loop ends */
    /* If ends */

    printf("\n");  
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
        printf("%d. sayı(number):%d\n",i+1,n[i]);

    else  /* Else for what if? */
    {
        break; 
    }                     
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

It should be easy to see what's wrong here.

Comment: i c/p but didnt work still gives expected primary-expression before "else" error before else

Comment: @user1944312 Read the comments I added to the code.

Answer (score 0):

The proper code would be as follows. See I have taken a size variable in case user enters -1 before five inputs.

```
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
    int n[10];
    int i,j,temp;

    for(i=0; i<5; i++) /*Wating to user */
    {
        printf("%d. Sayi giriniz(Enter NUmber)",i+1);
        scanf("%d",&n[i]);
        if(n[i]==-1)
            break;
    }
    int size = i;
    for(i=0; i<size-1; i++)
        for(j=i+1; j<size; j++)
            if(n[i]>n[j])
            {
                temp=n[i];
                n[i]=n[j];
                n[j]=temp;
            }

    printf("\n");
    for(i=0; i<size; i++)
        printf("%d. sayı(number):%d\n",i+1,n[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

If you want exactly 5 inputs, then you need not to break as the loop would terminate itself after five inputs.